# Find running report from WIReportServer.exe

Tags: business-objects

I have a query which keep coming back on my oracle database, without ever finishing.
I identified that it came from SAP Business Object, more precisely the WIReportServer.exe process. I have the Windows PID of the process.

Is there a way to find which BO report is linked to this process ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [WEBI Admin Tool](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/WebiAdminTool). Find the WebI Processing Server that matches the PID you have, click the gear icon to open it, select "Activities" from the Perspectives dropdown, then click the refresh icon at the far right.  This will present a list of all currently-processing activities.  You can then get the properties for each activity, which includes the user name and report name.

If this is a recurring issue, it might be easier to just add an END_SQL parameter to the universe.  This will add the BO user name and report name as a comment in every SQL statement that's generated.  You can then quickly identify the user just by checking the currently-running SQL in Oracle.  See [here](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/WebiAdminTool) for more info.